# Validating the Date format using selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a tab with name 'Preferences' where user can set the Date format in any format like `DD/MM/YYYY`, `DD.MM.YYYY`, `MM/DD/YYYY` etc and is applicable through out the web application

I have chosen a Date format `DD.MM.YYYY` and saved it

Now I need to validate a text field some where in my application where I give input say `01012001` and it should automatically take the input and convert to the preferred Date format `01.01.2001` where I have been saved in 'Preferences' tab

Could any one help me out how can I validate this in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case What I understand is you need to write function which will return you formatted date according to selected format.
Below function will do the work and return you formatted string.

```
public String parseDate(StringBuilder dateString, String formatString) {
        String separator = "";
        String slashSeperator = "/";
        if (formatString.contains(slashSeperator)) {
            separator = slashSeperator;
        } else {
            String dotSeparator = ".";
            if (formatString.contains(dotSeparator)) {
                separator = dotSeparator;
            }
        }
```

if (dateString.length() == 8) {
        dateString.insert(2, separator);
        dateString.insert(5, separator);
    } else {
        return "False Date Entered";
    }

    return dateString.toString();
}

Comment: If you are OK with this pleas mark this as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can check new Date library and its [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Use this formatter to parse date using [Date.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-). Examples are included within docs.